# Can't seem to get the for loop divided among several thread with open mp

Tags: c++, openmp

I've got this project to submit in college but it seems that I can't get the for loop to be divided among the several thread since I'm trying to print to thread number in the entire loop it just keeps printing zeros (indicating that only the master thread is handling the for loop) so here's the code

```
    // Filename: swarm1.cpp

       #include "swarm1.h"
       #include <omp.h>


       cParticle particles[MAX_PARTICLES];

       int main()
       {
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    //double times[500];
    //for (int i=0;i<500;i++){
        double sTime=omp_get_wtime();
        srand((unsigned)time(0));
        psoAlgorithm();
        double eTime=omp_get_wtime();
        cout<<eTime-sTime<<" Seconds \n";
        //times[i]=eTime-sTime;
    //}
    //double avg=0;
    //for (int i=0;i<500;i++)
        //avg+=times[i];
    /*cout << avg << " seconds" << endl;
    avg/=500;
    cout << avg << " seconds" << endl;
    */
    return 0;
       }

       void psoAlgorithm()
       {
    int gBest = 0;
    int gBestTest = 0;
    int epoch = 0;
    bool done = false;

    initialize();

    do
    {
      /* Two conditions can end this loop:
            if the maximum number of epochs allowed has been reached, or,
            if the Target value has been found.
      */
        if(epoch < MAX_EPOCHS){
            #pragma omp parallel for schedule (dynamic,5) 
            for(int i = 0; i <= MAX_PARTICLES - 1; i++)
            {
                cout << omp_get_thread_num() <<endl;
                /*for(int j = 0; j <= MAX_INPUTS - 1; j++)
                {
                    if(j < MAX_INPUTS - 1){
                        cout << particles[i].getData(j) << " + ";
                    }else{
                        cout << particles[i].getData(j) << " = ";
                    }
                } // j*/

                //cout << testProblem(i) << endl;
                if(testProblem(i) == TARGET)
                {
                    done = true;
                    cout << " particle " << i << " has found the target \n";
                    for(int j = 0; j <= MAX_INPUTS - 1; j++)
                {
                    if(j < MAX_INPUTS - 1){
                        cout << particles[i].getData(j) << " + ";
                    }else{
                        cout << particles[i].getData(j) << " = ";
                    }
                }
                }
            } // i

            gBestTest = minimum();

            //If any particle's pBest value is better than the gBest value,
            //make it the new gBest Value.
            if(abs(TARGET - testProblem(gBestTest)) < abs(TARGET - testProblem(gBest)))
            {
                gBest = gBestTest;
            }

            getVelocity(gBest);

            updateParticles(gBest);

            epoch += 1;

        }else{
            done = true;
        }

    }while(!done);

    cout << epoch << " epochs completed." << endl;

    return;
}

void initialize()
{
    int total;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule (dynamic,5) 
    for(int i = 0; i <= MAX_PARTICLES - 1; i++)
    {
        total = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j <= MAX_INPUTS - 1; j++)
        {
            particles[i].setData(j, getRandomNumber(START_RANGE_MIN, START_RANGE_MAX));
            total += particles[i].getData(j);
        } // j
        particles[i].setpBest(total);
    } // i

    return;
}

void getVelocity(int gBestIndex)
{
/* from Kennedy & Eberhart(1995).
    vx[][] = vx[][] + 2 * rand() * (pbestx[][] - presentx[][]) + 
                      2 * rand() * (pbestx[][gbest] - presentx[][])
*/
    int testResults, bestResults;
    float vValue;

    bestResults = testProblem(gBestIndex);
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule (dynamic,5) 
    for(int i = 0; i <= MAX_PARTICLES - 1; i++)
    {
        testResults = testProblem(i);
        vValue = particles[i].getVelocity() + 
            2 * gRand() * (particles[i].getpBest() - testResults) + 2 * gRand() * 
                                                    (bestResults - testResults);

        if(vValue > V_MAX){
            particles[i].setVelocity(V_MAX);
        }else if(vValue < -V_MAX){
            particles[i].setVelocity(-V_MAX);
        }else{
            particles[i].setVelocity(vValue);
        }
    } // i
}

void updateParticles(int gBestIndex)
{
    int total, tempData;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule (dynamic,5) 
    for(int i = 0; i <= MAX_PARTICLES - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= MAX_INPUTS - 1; j++)
        {
            if(particles[i].getData(j) != particles[gBestIndex].getData(j))
            {
                tempData = particles[i].getData(j);
                particles[i].setData(j, tempData + static_cast<int>(particles[i].getVelocity()));
            }
        } // j

        //Check pBest value.
        total = testProblem(i);
        if(abs(TARGET - total) < particles[i].getpBest())
        {
            particles[i].setpBest(total);
        }

    } // i

}

int testProblem(int index)
{
    int total = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= MAX_INPUTS - 1; i++)
    {
        total += particles[index].getData(i);
    } // i

    return total;
}

float gRand()
{
    // Returns a pseudo-random float between 0.0 and 1.0
    return float(rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));
}

int getRandomNumber(int low, int high)
{
    // Returns a pseudo-random integer between low and high.
    return low + int(((high - low) + 1) * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)); 
}

int minimum()
{
//Returns an array index.
    int winner = 0;
    bool foundNewWinner;
    bool done = false;

    do
    {
        foundNewWinner = false;
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule (dynamic,2) 
        for(int i = 0; i <= MAX_PARTICLES - 1; i++)
        {
            if(i != winner){             //Avoid self-comparison.
                //The minimum has to be in relation to the Target.
                if(abs(TARGET - testProblem(i)) < abs(TARGET - testProblem(winner)))
                {
                    winner = i;
                    foundNewWinner = true;
                }
            }
        } // i

        if(foundNewWinner == false)
        {
            done = true;
        }

    }while(!done);

    return winner;
}
```

Comment: Remember that more threads != more speed

Comment: I know but it is only working on the master thread .. how can I divide it among the threads